# Database structure, one big entity for multiple entities

Tags: sql, database, architecture, structure

Suppose that I have a store-website where user can leave comments about any product.

Suppose that I have tables(entities) in my website database: let it be 'Shoes', 'Hats' and 'Skates'.
I don't want to create separate "comments" table for every entity (like 'shoes_comments', 'hats_comments', 'skates_comments'). 
My idea is to somehow store all the comments in one big table.

One way to do this, that I thought of, is to create a table:

```
table (comments): 
ID (int, Primary Key), 
comment (text),  
Product_id (int), 
isSkates (boolean), 
isShoes (boolean), 
isHats (boolean)
```

and like flag for every entity that could have comments.

Then when I want to get comments for some product the SELECT query would look like:

```
SELECT comment 
FROM comments, ___SOMETABLE___
WHERE ____SOMEFLAG____ = TRUE 
  AND ___SOMETABLE___.ID = comments.Product_id
```

Is this an efficient way to implement database for needed functionality?
What other ways i can do this?>

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to make one table for the comments and use a foreign key of other tables in the comments table.

Comment: My idea is somewhat different. As i understood your idea: add a Foreign Key to global Comments table for every Entity table.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this feels odd.

Do you indeed have one separate table for each product type? Don't they have common fields (e.g. name, description, price, product image, etc.)?

My recommendation as for tables: `product` for common fields, `comments` with foreign key to `product` but no `hasX` columns, `hat` with only the fields that are specific to the hat product line. The primary key in `hat` is either the `product` PK or an individual unique value (then you'd need an extra field for the foreign key to `product`).

Comment: Ok, i guess for products for one type, this is not a difficult one. But in my situation i have entities of totally separate things (suppose: Organisation, Staff, Technical equipment) and i need to store comments for them...

Comment: Ok, I was mislead by your examples then, sorry. Still, you need only one `comment` table - if you're willing to bend the rules a bit. You don't want to have a foreign key column in `comment` for each entity that has comments I guess. What if you don't have an actual foreign key column but one column declared as `parent_id` in `comment`? I suppose the relationship from `X` to `comment` can be uni-directional? One alternative would be to have a join table for each `X` to `comment` e.g `shoe_x_comment`, `hat_x_comment`.

Answer (score 0):

The "normalized" way to do this is to add one more entity (say, "Product") that groups all characteristics common to shoes, hats and skates (including comments)

```
              +-- 0..1 [Shoe]
              |
[Product] 1 --+-- 0..1 [Hat]
    1         |
    |         +-- 0..1 [Skate]
    *
[Comment]
```

Besides performance considerations, the drawback here is that there is nothing in the data model preventing a row in Product to be referenced both by a row in Shoe and one in Hat.

There are other alternatives too (each with perks & flaws) - you might want to read something about "jpa inheritance strategies" - you'll find java-specific articles that discuss your same issue (just ignore the java babbling and read the rest)

Personally, I often end up using a single table for all entities in a hierarchy (shoes, hats and skates in our case) and sacrificing constraints on the altar of performance and simplicity (eg: not null in a field that is mandatory for shoes but not for hats and skates).

Comment: In situation where i will create table "COMMENTABLE" and from entity tables (hat, shoes, skates) connect them to it with 1:1 relation, will this work?

Comment: Yep - that's the idea! Before going for it, you will want to consider performances... eg: to add a new Shoe you'll need two insert statements (1 for Commentable and 1 for Shoe) - if you have the id of a comment and you want to navigate to its owner entity, you'll need (possibly several) union clauses, as you don't know in advance in what table the entity is (may be Shoe, Hat or Skate)...

Comment: The trouble here really is that E/R does not do inheritance - one may simulate it (like in the 3 JPA strategies), but he has to accept some tradeoff